# Is there a better way to do these boiler plate tests in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

Currently using AutoFixture for the boiler plate code of guard methods. But is there a better way to do the rest of the boiler plate code in the unit tests? Or is there no need to test in the first place?

```
        fixture.Create<TestClass>();
        var testException = new ArgumentNullBehavior();
        var assertion = new GuardClauseAssertion(fixture, testException);
        assertion.Verify(typeof(TestClass).GetConstructors());

        //Boiler plate part below:
        var testClass = new TestClass(lang, refer, link, info, title, description);
        Assert.AreEqual(lang, testClass.Lang);
        Assert.AreEqual(refer, testClass.Refer);
        Assert.AreEqual(link, testClass.Link);
        Assert.AreEqual(info, testClass.Info);
        Assert.AreEqual(title, testClass.Title);
        Assert.AreEqual(description, testClass.Description);
```

Comment: If a unittest for a class has enough relevancy is hard to predict from the outside (some sort of cost based analysis the price of testing vs. the price of NOT testing) . The class under test here feels like a DTO. Those classes typically get created by a class mapper, Serializer or Persistent Framework so most things are tested indirectly by test of those facilities. I tend to not test DTOs.

Comment: It's not generated, but it's more or less a DTO. It's requests to send from the controller to the service.

Comment: Check [AutoFixture Idioms](https://docs.educationsmediagroup.com/unit-testing-csharp/autofixture/idioms).

Comment: @Pat wording error from my side. I should have said "instantiated" instead of "created".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend installing *FluentAssertions* package:
`NuGet\Install-Package FluentAssertions -Version 6.9.0`

Then you could replace those manual assertions using object equivalency method:
`actualTestClass.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedTestClass);`

In general this package has various functionality that might save you from writing this boilerplate code you have posted. Ex.: checking if `DateTime` fields are close to certain value.

Here's the link for docs - https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/